# JavaFX ListView basic app

Tags: java, javafx

I am newbie in JavaFX and i wanted to try something to begin with.. So i created simple ListView, but when i tried to run the program, instead of 4 listView items (Cat, Dog, Mouse, Horse) There is only submit button in rigt top corner.
Can someone help me out what i did wrong? Thanks for any advice!

```
package main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;


public class Main extends Application {
 Stage window;
    Scene scene;
    Button button;
    ListView<String> listView;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Try listView");
        button = new Button("Submit");

        listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.getItems().addAll("Cat", "Dog", "Mouse", "Horse");
        listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        button.setOnAction(e -> buttonClicked());


        VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
        layout.getChildren().addAll(button);

        scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();


    }
    private void buttonClicked() {
        String message = "";
        ObservableList<String> movies;
        movies = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

        for (String m: movies) {
            message += m + "/n";
        }
        System.out.println(message);
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't add the `ListView` to a layout/the scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your scene, you are only adding the `Button` to it.  Change the following line of code:

```
layout.getChildren().addAll(listView, button);
```

By doing this, you will add the `ListView` followed by the `Button`.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.. Thanks a lot for helping!